# time.h library default functions C++

Tags: c++, linux, time

i was wonder if the localtime() function work on Linux? i though there is another command for that but i cant remember it now

apparently my assignment have to work on linux or it doesn't count for marks and my parents does not know how to use it

Comment: What is your assignment? also bad bad parents for not knowing the linux c headers.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: Not knowing that certain Linux functions work or not does'nt make anyone's parents or for that matter anyone bad.

Comment: @Als and for everybody else reading this. Ricedragons parents are most likely awesome for teaching him programming. I made a crude joke about them not knowing the particulars of this fairly exotic question. I'm happy for ricedragon and his endeavours.  I apologize for any ills my joke might have provoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `localtime()` function works on Linux. Check the reference [**here**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_localtime.htm).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) localtime() should work perfectly fine with Linux.

From the linked:

```
    #include <time.h>
    //...
    struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
    struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
```

If that declaration is the same localtime() that you're asking about (and I assume it is) then you should be just fine using it on Linux based machines.